# How to realize efficient broadcast in the Kademlia p2p protocol?

Tags: networking, p2p, network-protocols, kademlia

I am currently researching about the [Kademlia](http://xlattice.sourceforge.net/components/protocol/kademlia/specs.html) peer to peer protocol and I am curious if someone knows of techniques or approaches to efficiently broadcast an information/a message?

There is a paper [Effcient Broadcast in Structured P2P Networks](http://www.sics.se/~seif/Publications/paper3.pdf), which describes a way of broadcasting in [Chord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_%28peer-to-peer%29). Their idea is to partition the network in two parts and send the broadcast message to the first node in each of these partitions. The contacted nodes again partition their "subnet" and perform the same actions. Using this technique you can broadcast the message on a spanning tree through the network. However, I am having problems applying it to Kademlia, because it is difficult to reliably partition the Kademlia network.

Has someone an idea how this could be achieved or what alternative approaches exist?

I do not want to massively flood the network as this has bad implications on the network load and causes a lot of redundant traffic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I was able to find a possible solution in this paper: [P2P based intrusion detection](http://www.hiradastechnika.hu/data/upload/file/2009/2009%20I/Pages_from_HT0901a_2.pdf). It turns out that it is indeed possible to use the network topology in Kademlia to partition the network effectively